# Where is Silver Searcher after installing via Cygwin installer?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I don't want to install through another method and have it duplicated somewhere somehow on my system. I'm in Windows 10, re-ran the Cygwin installer to install Silver Searcher, no idea where to find it now. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the package list or cygcheck.

https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/the_silver_searcher/the_silver_searcher-2.1.0-1

the binary is at

```
usr/bin/ag.exe
```

Comment: That's within the cygwin64 dir, right? I don't even have usr/bin/. Will check out cygcheck. Thanks.

Comment: `usr/bin` is mounted on `bin` if you are looking from explorer.